# etcd cluster healthcheck | aws ELB

Tags: aws, aws-elb, etcd

I am setting up a 3 node etcd cluster behind a AWS ELB. I would like to know how can I setup a healthcheck on the ELB for the 3 nodes, preferably using the v3 api endpoint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was so simple:

```
http://$hostname:2379/health
```

If using client-to-server TLS, the endpoint is https. The cert for the host or the CA may need to be provided.